# VB6 Debugging through Visual studio Attached Process VS2017 and above

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vb6

How can i debugging VB6 project and its classes from attached process by using the Visual Studio 2017 and above version,
I am using visual studio 2017.

Comment: This (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robgruen/2004/11/09/debugging-vb6-binaries-in-visual-studio-net/) blog post describes how to debug (using Visual Studio) a VB6 dll being called (com interop) from a .net app.  I can't tell from your question if this what you're looking for, but it may provide some assistance.

Comment: I don't know whether this is still possible. It used to be possible with `Visual Studio 2015` - see instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22183371/15639) but I don't know about later versions. There are more instructions in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robgruen/2004/11/09/debugging-vb6-binaries-in-visual-studio-net/)

Comment: Yes for VS2015 is possible but i use now VS2017, and with this version of VS i do not know yet,  how to Debug VB6... Thanks for any help @MarkJ