# Can we debug the code present in vb6 from visual studio2019

Tags: debugging, vb6, visual-studio-2019

I have code present in VB6 and I called a function of VB6 from VS2019.

My code:

```
protected void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    SellitEcom31.System ss = new SellitEcom31.System();
    ss.InitializeSite(0);   //Function present in vb6
}
```

My question is how can i debug to Vb6 code from VS2019 (when debug hits the InitializeSite() function in VS2019 , how will the debug enter into VB6 IDE )

Note : I enabled

1)  Options | Debugging | Edit and Continue | Enable native Edit and Continue

2)  Options | Debugging | General | Use Managed Compatibility Mode

Comment: I don't know whether this is still possible. It used to be possible with `Visual Studio 2015` - see instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22183371/15639) but I don't know about later versions. There are more instructions in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robgruen/2004/11/09/debugging-vb6-binaries-in-visual-studio-net/)

Comment: Do you have the VB6 IDE installed? Do you want to debug there? That's what I recommend if its possible.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is how can i debug to Vb6 code from VS2019 (when debug
>   hits the InitializeSite() function in VS2019 , how will the debug
>   enter into VB6 IDE )

**I'm afraid that the answer is negative.**

For VS2015 and previous versions, we can debug DLLS in VS which are generated by VB6 projects by changing some Settings like the options you have enabled. But since VS2017, It seems that it is no longer supported.

Thanks to MarkJ for the documentation, I don't seem to have found any documentation on the latest version of VS that supports debugging VB6 code. Due to it, l have [reported it to the DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/839653/can-we-debug-the-code-present-in-vb6-from-visual-s.html).Also, you can vote it and add a comment(**If I don't describe it in detail**) so that it will call the attention of the support team.

**As a suggestion**, [try converting your vb6 project to a vb.net project](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/dotnet/ca0956fb-b3d8-48a0-8c85-3559ae02dc0f.htm) so that VS can be used directly. It can be a complex process and is just as a suggestion.

Hope it could help you.